# Configuring JNDI InitialContext from XML file

Tags: java, configuration, datasource, jndi, context.xml

I'd like to define JNDI lookups in my app's own XML config file (somewhat similar to Tomcat's `context.xml`), and then reference them in my app. Then, under the hood, the app uses JNDI to look the objects up with the information stored in the XML file.

For instance, given the following snippet from my app's XML config file:

```
<app>
    <!-- lots of stuff -->

    <dataSource name="jdbc/myDB"
        maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="mysqluser" password="mysqlpassword" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB"/>

    <!-- lots of stuff -->
</app>
```

Then, in my app:

```
public class DataSourceProvider {
    public DataSource lookupDataSource(String name) {
        DataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("Database");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // Handle...
        }

        return dataSource;
    }
}

DataSourceProvider dsp = new DataSourceProvider();
DataSource myDB = dsp.lookupDataSource("myDB");
```

**How do I link these two concepts together?** Say the `<dataSource/>` XML element gets read into a `DataSourceVO` object. How do I configure the `InitialContext` instance from the `DataSourceVO` instance, such that we can perform the JNDI lookup? Thanks in advance!

**Update**: I found this example:

```
try{   
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();   
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,   
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");   
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

    String securityPrincipal = domain + "\\" + user;

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrincipal);   
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);   
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + domainController);   

    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);   
} catch (AuthenticationException ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch(NamingException nex){   
    nex.printStackTrace();   
}
```

Is *this* what I'm looking for? That way, I could read my XML into a `Hashtable` (or something similar) and then create the `InitialContext` from that table? Is that all there is to it?!?

Comment: Is you app an web app? If yes, why wouldn't you use JNDI in context.xml? If not, have you considered using spring and simply use dependency injection?

Comment: Thanks @YoriKusanagi - no, Spring is not an option and no, this is a reusable JAR, not a WAR.

Comment: ...(so no `context.xml` is available).

Answer (score 0):

Try Spring http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-connections, see 14.3.1 DataSource

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>
```

If Spring is not an option then you can configure the data source using Properties

```
Properties props = new Properties();

... load from properties file or XML 

BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
for(Entry e : props.entrySet()) {
    ds.addConnectionProperty((String)e.getKey(), (String)e.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy Dorofeev (+1) - how could I make this work with a Javax Mail session as well? I had scoped out JNDI because whether I'm specifying `jdbc/myDB` or `smtp/myMailServer` it would work all the same. For instance, say my JAR happens to ship with a `context.xml` file that contains a resource for a mail server instead of a RDBMS server - I still think JNDI is the way to go here.

Comment: Hey there @Evgeniy Dorofeev - can you look at my update and see if that's what I'm looking for? Thanks again!